# PHP odbc connection error

Tags: php, oracle, odbc

I am new with using OBDC in php. I have an error upon connection:

```
[function.odbc-connect] SQL error [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Invalid string or buffer length
```

PHP ODBC

```
$string_serve = "(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = host.com)(PORT = 1404)))
      (CONNECT_DATA =(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = SERVE)))";

$string_serve ="DRIVER={SQL Server};
                  SERVER='server.com';
                  DATABASE= db;"

   $conn = odbc_connect($string_serve, 'user', 'pass');
```

I have tried using both variables

Comment: That doesn't look like an ODBC connection string to me. Have a look at the examples on the [`obdc_connect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-connect.php) documentation page.

Comment: You can't use a Microsoft SQL Server driver to connect to Oracle. What Oracle client software (full, instantclient, etc.) have you got installed?

Comment: I havent. Would that conflict with the porting in wampp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to keep the connection details out of the source code.

Create a .odbc.ini file somewhere not publicly accessible. Define a data source like this:

```
[my_database]
Driver       = /usr/lib/libmyodbc3.so
SERVER       = server.com
DATABASE     = db
```

Let the odbc driver find it:

```
putenv('ODBCINI=/your-application-path/etc/.odbc.ini');
```

Using exported variables at Apache-startup etc. might not work as avariables are sometimes not passed to the application.

Use a simple odbc_connect() in your PHP code:

```
$conn = odbc_connect('my_database', 'username', 'password')
```